# Returning a "readable" number in PHP

Tags: php, rounding

I am trying to receive a result of a math operation with small numbers (maximum 8 decimals), I receive a float result, but in a format that make the other numbers stay with an error:

```
$a = round($x, 8); //returns 0.0478674, that's correct
$b = round($y,8); //returns 0.04786261, that's correct
$z = $a - $b; //z returns 4.7899999999976E-6, and not ‭0.00000479‬ as I was expecting
```

I tried as well

```
$w = round($z,8); //but w returns 4.79E-6, and not 0.00000479‬ as I was expecting
```

My problem is because the number `4.7899999999976E-6` give an error in other calcs and it's a ugly number to show to the user.

How can I make this number be `0.00000479`‬?

Answer (score 1):

you can use [number_format](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php):

```
$w = number_format($z,8);
```

Answer (score 0):

number_format should do what you require, from the help: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php

For your specific requirement here:

```
$w = number_format($z,8);
```